# Python | PhantomJS not clicking on element

Tags: python, selenium, automation, phantomjs

I have been trying to solve this for an entire week now and this is my last shot at this (asking stackoverflow).

I use phantomjs with selenium to go to the login page of YouTube and fill in the credentials and log in.

I get to the login page and it manages to fill in the email, but no matter what I try, it won't click on the "next" button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["-phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent-"] = (
    "-Mozilla-5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit-537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome-34.0.1847.137 Safari-537.36-"
    )

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)

driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)
driver.get("https://youtube.com")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("yt-uix-button-content").click()
print("Logging in...")
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys("email")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ZFr60d").click()

driver.save_screenshot('testing4.png')
```

Now I have tried all these

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span""").click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#identifierNext>content>span").click()

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()

driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
```

and none of these works. I tried the javascript command aswell.

I would also like to add that clicking on the element works perfectly fine with selenium without PhantomJS.

I would really appreciate it if anyone here could help me.

EDIT:

This info might be helpful. After clicking "Next", it takes about a second to get to the password part. It's a sliding animation.

This question has yet not been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

A couple of words:

1. The locator you have used to identify the `Sign in` button is not unique. Consider constructing an unique `xpath` for the `Sign in` button.
2. The locator you have used to identify the `Email or phone` also needs to be modified a bit.
3. You can consider to use the locator `id` to identify and click on the `Next` button.
4. Here is the code block which does the same and prints out `Clicked on Next Button` on the console.

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   import time

   dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
   dcap["-phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent-"] = (
       "-Mozilla-5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit-537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome-34.0.1847.137 Safari-537.36-"
       )

   driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe")

   driver.get("https://youtube.com")
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-primary']/span[@class='yt-uix-button-content']").click()
   print("Logging in...")
   email_phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")
   email_phone.send_keys("debanjanb")
   driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
   print("Clicked on Next Button")
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Query.

Comment: Wait, testing it.

Comment: Code is well Tested and works at its best on my Windows 8 PC. Thanks

Comment: What didn't work? On which line are you seeing the error? What is the error all about? Can you update all these info in the question area for further analysis please? Thanks

Comment: I am not getting any errors. I just screenshotted after the code and it is still on the login page at the email part, it has not clicked on next.

Comment: It still did not click on the next button.

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: @Dainel: would it be, that PhantomJS as webdriver was specifically blocked? would the original script work with Firefox?